# ASP.NET GridView DropDownList in Edit assign what is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upgrade" SortExpression="Upgrade">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelUpgrade" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Upgrade") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUpgrade" runat="server" Width="100px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="5">4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="6">5</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

When I click edit on the GridView I need to take the value of the LabelUpgrade and assign it to the selected item in the DropDownList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<asp:DropDownList ... SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Upgrade") %>'>
```

Comment: In the aspx page. The DropDownList doesn't have a SelectedValue property. You can set the Selected property in the ListItem.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz: Yes it does. It's inherited from [the `ListControl` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't have an option for SelectedValue

Comment: @Tsukasa: It's definitely there. If it doesn't appear in the properties list, just type it into the markup.

Comment: @RichardDeeming ***Could you please test it? It throws exception*** - `The 'SelectedValue' property cannot be set declaratively.`

Comment: @RichardDeeming I take it back. I was testing the `DropDownList` without GridView. Besides `SelectedValue` is set as `[Browsable(false)]` which is why we do not get intellisense.

Comment: Ok it did accept that as valid but I am getting has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value. The data in the database is indeed a value in the item list?

Comment: @Tsukasa: What's the value in the database?

Comment: I have tried all of the values from the list and each one of them throws the error.

Comment: @Tsukasa - This seems best answer to me... it is working in my test also. I am removing my answer.

Comment: @Tsukasa: Are you using the same values that you posted in your question? If not, bear in mind that the `SelectedValue` is case-sensitive; the value has to match *precisely* with the `Value` set on the `ListItem`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice a type, the update work the first time but every other time it failed because I was in fact pointing to the wrong control so the value didn't exist. Thanks for all of your help.